# Namespace undefined error in javascript to execute ajax method from asp.net page

Tags: javascript, .net, ajaxpro

I am Using Ajax Pro

I am  not getting any error on my machine when i test the web site but getting an error of TimeSheet is undefined (TimeSheet is the namespace) from the hosting.

I get this error in the following cdoe from javascript function

```
try
{
var response = TimeSheet.DAL.ApexDalc.PopulateDuration(d1, d3);
}
catch(txt)
{
 alert(txt.message);
 return false;
}

alert(response.value.Tables[0].Rows[0].Hours);
```

I have registered Ajaxpro in the page load with `AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(DAL.ApexDalc));`

I have added httphandlers in web.config also:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajaxpro/*.ashx" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory, AjaxPro.2"/>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Can you suggest what can be the cause of error in the web site from hosting server?

Thanks